# WiFi suggestion API fail on Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I've been trying to use the new Android [WiFi Suggestion API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest) with the code taken exactly from the example, but each time I try to connect to a network, when I call `wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList)` I get status 3 in response, which (according to [this site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#STATUS_SUGGESTION_CONNECTION_FAILURE_IP_PROVISIONING)) means *IP provision failure*. What does that mean? How can I handle that?

My app has all the required permissions and even some more (`CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`, `INTERNET`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE`, `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`), and the location is turned on. I tried with a few WiFi networks (all are visible in the WiFi settings), but still got the same IP provisioning error.

Comment: Even in the case this question is very old: Add the code what you wrote exactly. Might be you you used a wrong property in the suggestion builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue and found it quite confusing because `status = 3` can mean two things: `STATUS_SUGGESTION_APPROVAL_REJECTED_BY_USER` or `STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_ERROR_ADD_DUPLICATE`.

In my case it was the latter. Basically the suggestion is remembered once submitted. I solved this by removing my suggestion before it's added:

```java
wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(suggestions)
val status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestions)
```

Comment: This question is quite old, but as far as I remember, this was probably also the case here. When I tried to add the suggestion for the first time it probably worked, but I accidentally dismissed or tapped something on the dialog, and then started getting this error code all the time. I wasn't aware of its alternative meanings. This could be very helpful to others. Thank you!

Comment: this fixes the issue, but can you share your implementation how you to make wifi connection really connect, if it is possible, thanks

Comment: With the suggestion API, the Android system will decide whether to connect or not. If you are already connected to a secured wifi with good signal strength and internet connection, the system won't change to your suggestion.

Comment: Is there any workaround when user selects forget network or disconnect network and doesn't connect to the wifi? Since, status code is 0 which means suggestion is successful. Is there any way to check if user clicked forget network or disconnect?